# python copy string from position to position

Tags: python, string, position, copy

I've got a string test_string like 'Hello, two is a number'" and I want to copy the characters between position 7 and 12. In the programming language I use:

```
test_string = 'Hello, two is a number'
new_string = string_copy(test_string, 7, 12)
```

the value of new_string would be ' two i'. My example might be a bit stupid, but does a function exist in Python equal to string_copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a built-in feature, that’s called *slicing*:

```
'Hello, two is a number'[7:12]
```

or

```
test_string = 'Hello, two is a number'
new_string = test_string[7:12]
```

You seem to have miscounted though, as the result will be 'two i' (without leading space).

*edit: Or, as Zero Piraeus points out, your language uses 1-based indexing in contrast to python*

See also https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: That should be `'Hello, two is a number'[6:12]` ... question assumes 1-based indexing and closed [intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Terminology) (which is reasonable, just not how Python does it), whereas Python's slicing is [zero-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) and half-open.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your method works like a charm. I checked the GML (Game Maker Language) documentation which uses 1-based indexing indeed.